# Hyper-V VM and Browser-Sync times out

Tags: hyper-v, browser-sync

I've used Windows Hyper-V VM for web development for couple years now, running a simple Debian box with all the tools I need and what would be a pain to run on Windows. Standard LEMP, with a set of tools for front-end development.

Everything else works great, except for Browser-Sync. I've tried searching for any issues related to running Browser-Sync on VM, and being accessible from the host machine. I'm proxying development address on the VM (eg. local.example.com) and while I can access the Browser-Sync UI on local.example.com:3001 on the host machine, connection to the proxied site at local.example.com:3000 times out. No error message, no nothing. I've tried forcing the host ip with --host, tried different ports and running different versions of Browser-Sync, through Gulp and stand-alone from command line. Port forwarding or anything like that shouldn't be an issue with Hyper-v VM with a virtual external switch. I had this same issue on Windows 8.1 Hyper-V, and now on Windows 10.

Has anyone had any issues, when running Browser-Sync on VM, and trying to access your development site from host? I'm at a loss here, don't really know what to even look for.

Answer (score 2):

I also looked on making this work with a centos vm on virtual box.
You probably missed to add your host in your debian machine.

So the steps that worked for me are:

1. Start the browser sync with a proxy (I used it from console)
   browser-sync start --proxy local.example.com
2. Make sure you have local.example.com in your windows hosts file and that it points to your linux vm ip
3. Make sure you have local.example.com in your linux hosts file (browser sync on the linux machine will access that url)
4. access local.example.com:3000 (the port may be changed) and that should take you to your normal site, but being proxied through browser sync